# #ifdef python3 print_with_parantheses #else print_using_python2_style #endif

Tags: python, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to achieve something like "conditional interpretation" in [python](/questions/tagged/python) similar to the conditional compilation [c](/questions/tagged/c) pre-processor directives allow? I would like to use the same code in Python 2.7 and Python 3, keeping the few [print](/questions/tagged/print)-s that code has right now. That is, I would like to have **syntactically incorrect code** not interpreted in some cases.

A simple work-around like this one:

```
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    print("init message")
else:
    print "init message"
```

results in a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Is there any way to tell the interpreter to skip evaluation?

Comment: no, no there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Use `from __future__ import print_function`

You can check the documentation here: [**future**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/__future__.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do it differently: instead of conditional interpretation, you use a [`__future__` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements), by which you can write code conforming to "future" syntax and keep backwards compatible:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

print("init message")
```

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python where the feature becomes standard.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this actually solves my current problem. I guess the answer to the "conditional interpretation" question is no, isn't it?